# DropDownList Not Being Refreshed after a JS alert window

Tags: c#, asp.net

There is an asp.net page in which I have a drop down list server control. This control is responsible for filtering the products based upon the categories bound to it. I'm not using the SelectedIndexChanged event of the DropDownList and instead I left a button just beside it.

The control's first item is simply a text (not any product category), "Select One"! 
What if some user presses the 'search' button without choosing any option.. Simply I am going to handle it in code behind with an 'if' statement. Here's my code:

```
if(ddlCategories.SelectedIndex==0)
{
string msgbox = "alert('" + GiftShop.Properties.Resources.MustSelectAnItem+ "');";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "msgbox", msgbox, true);
}
```

But it's working even when I choose a real category (and not the Text "Select One").
By the way, there is an UpdatePanel holding the controls above.

I don't know what might be reason.

I appreciate if anybody give me some idea! Thanks in advance..

Comment: Did you try putting breakpoint on if condition? Does it go inside if?

Comment: BTW, why are you not doing this in directly from javascript rather than from code behind?

Comment: Your code works for me. How are you populating the options for the drop-down box? Maybe you are rebuilding the drop-down box on every postback, causing the selected index to always be zero?

Comment: Is the rest of your code in the 'else' statement?

Answer (score 0):

If "Select One" is not a Product Category why you use `SelectedIndex` in your Coding...?

you can try that by `DropDown Text` Property...

```
if (ddlCategories.Text.ToUpper() == "SELECT ONE")
```

Comment: You see, I use SelectedIndex since the first item is 'Select one' and if for any reason the user just clicks the sort button (without choosing a category) then the application goes for an error. The reason is that, there is no product category by the name of 'Select one'! Anyways, I tested your suggestion and nothing happens :( Anyway Thanks for your help my friend!